# partial ordering in weight lattice

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Is there a command in Sage to find out the set of dominant weights less than or equal to a given dominant weight in the weight lattice ? Where the ordering is the partial ordering in the weight lattice: $\lambda \leq \mu$ if and only if $\mu-\lambda$ is a nonnegative integral linear combination of positive roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this maybe

```
sage: RS=RootSystem(['A',3])                                                    
sage: WL=RS.weight_lattice()
sage: RL=RS.root_lattice()                                                  
sage: l1,l2,l3=WL.gens()                                                        
sage: def neighbors(l): 
....:     for r in RL.gens(): 
....:         delta = l - r 
....:         if delta.is_dominant(): 
....:             yield delta 
....:                                                                           
sage: X = RecursivelyEnumeratedSet([3*(l1+l2)], neighbors)                      
sage: list(X)                                                                   
[3*Lambda[1] + 3*Lambda[2],
 Lambda[1] + 4*Lambda[2],
 4*Lambda[1] + Lambda[2] + Lambda[3],
 2*Lambda[1] + 2*Lambda[2] + Lambda[3],
 3*Lambda[2] + Lambda[3],
 3*Lambda[1] + 2*Lambda[3],
 Lambda[1] + Lambda[2] + 2*Lambda[3],
 3*Lambda[1] + Lambda[2],
 Lambda[1] + 2*Lambda[2],
 2*Lambda[1] + Lambda[3],
 Lambda[2] + Lambda[3]]
```